# angularJS ngClick on Image Not Called

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am attempting to place an outline around each item on my web page with a class that starts with "col-" and then place an image in the top right corner of the outline for the user to click as follows;

```
<img id="elementMenu" src="Images/ElementMenu.png" style="display: none" ng-click="menuClick()" />
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1">
            <h1>This is my heading</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-1">
            <p>This is my content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
            <h1>This is my heading</h1>
            <p>This is my content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my script is;

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute", "ui.bootstrap"]);
}());

(function () {
    var app = angular.module("myApp");
    var $element = {};

    var editorController = function ($scope) {
        $scope.menuClick = function () {
            alert("Menu clicked");
        };

        $("document").ready(function () {
            $("*[class*='col-']")
            .mouseenter(function () {
                $element = $(this);
                $element.addClass("highlightColumn");

                var offset = $element.offset();
                var width = $element.width();

                var $menu = $("#elementMenu");
                var menuWidth = $menu.width()
                var menuOffset = $menu.offset();

                var menuLeft = offset.left + width - menuWidth;
                $menu.css({ position: "fixed", margin: 0, left: menuLeft, top: offset.top, display: "block" })
            })
            .mouseleave(function () {
                $element.removeClass("highlightColumn");
                $("#elementMenu").css({ display: "none" });
            });
        });
    };

    app.controller("myController", ["$scope", myController]);
}());
```

When the mouse is over the column element the border and the image are displayed however clicking on the image doesn't display the alert.  If I change the style of the image to "display: 'block'" and refresh the page I can click on the image and display the alert however after the image is repositioned as the mouse is moved over a column element clicking the image no longer displays the alert.

Is there an issue with hiding and displaying the image or repositioning it that prevents the click event from triggering?

Comment: Check your browser console ;)

Comment: maybe just cover the img with an span and put the ng-click on the span... coz Im pretty sure its basic js to have events blocked when items are hidden :)

Comment: Checked the console - no errors only log outputs I have used for debugging :(

Comment: Jony-Y: My problem is that once the image is displayed again clicking it doesn't display my alert; i.e. the function isn't called.